# Android pragmatic button background drawn incorrectly

Tags: android, button, drawable

I am trying to make some buttons at run time for my app. For the most part, it works, so I know I am close.

--SOLVED-- The problem is, the background first of all doesn't draw for the normal UNPRESSED state. But that's because I don't see a "normal" state to choose from. So how do I set the normal state? /--SOLVED--

Second, it does draw when I tap on the text, but it draws the background around the third button, no matter what button was clicked. Why won't it draw the gdPressed drawable around whatever button is being pressed?

Here's my code:

```
GradientDrawable gdNormal = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { 0, 0, 0 });
gdNormal.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
gdNormal.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 });
gdNormal.setStroke(1, contentColor);

GradientDrawable gdPressed = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { 0, 0, contentColor });
gdPressed.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
gdPressed.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 });
gdPressed.setStroke(1, contentColor);

StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, gdPressed);
sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused }, gdPressed);
// sld.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_normal}, gdPressed); //
// no such state

btnAlarmSettings.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
btnSettings.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
btnSkipNextAlarm.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);

btnAlarmSettings.setText("Alarm Settings");
btnAlarmSettings.setTextColor(contentColor);
btnAlarmSettings.setTextSize(24);
btnAlarmSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnAlarmSettings_clicked(v);
    }
});

btnSettings.setText("Settings");
btnSettings.setTextColor(contentColor);
btnSettings.setTextSize(24);
btnSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnSettings_clicked(v);
    }
});

btnSkipNextAlarm.setText("Skip Next Alarm");
btnSkipNextAlarm.setTextColor(contentColor);
btnSkipNextAlarm.setTextSize(24);
btnSkipNextAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // not implemented yet
    }
});

llButtonRow.addView(btnAlarmSettings);
llButtonRow.addView(btnSettings);
llButtonRow.addView(btnSkipNextAlarm);

btnAlarmSettings.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
btnSettings.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
btnSkipNextAlarm.setBackgroundDrawable(sld);
```

Thanks, @AwadKab. You solved the missing normal drawables.

I still have the problem of when I press on either of the first two buttons, the highlight always appears around the "Skip Next Alarm" button, instead of the button being clicked. The highlighted gdPressed state never shows around the first two buttons. When I click on the first two buttons, their associated onClickListener does fire and the next activity does start. It's just that the highlight doesn't show around the button.

Furthermore, when I return from the follow-on activity (by pressing the back button) and I return to this activity, the strokes around the buttons become incomplete. Specifically, the right side of the first two buttons disappear. The third button is complete.

Answer (score 0):

To draw normal state try this :

```
sld.addState(new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_focused,-android.R.attr.state_pressed }, gdNormal);
```

See `-` before `android.R.attr.state_focused` and `android.R.attr.state_pressed`

Hope this helped you.